# Can't run Qt program on another computer

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu

I have copied my qt C++ program into another computer running the same Ubuntu version but it did not work. The terminal told that it can't find the:

```
libQt5PrintSupport.so.5
libQt5Core.so.5
libQt5Widgets.so.5
libQt5Gui.so.5
```

I then installed the qt essentials and qt base and afterwords verified that these libraries were installed but still got the same errors.
Then I tried to install the Qt creator itself but it gave me errors considering pre-build C++ files like function multiple definitions (of course no such errors on my computer)
While on my computer I even didn't have to use the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`
Please help

Comment: `apt-file search libQt5PrintSupport.so`, install the according packages then. You might have to first install `apt-file`, btw.

Comment: don't forget to start a new shell once you've installed the packages so that any updates can be loaded into that environment

Comment: I have install everything that apt-file told me then rebooted the system still the same error

Comment: `Qt5PrintSupport` is relatively new and depending on your ubuntu version it won't be there by default. You need to install a newer version of qt, which you might've done in the first computer but not the second.

Comment: In all computers I have installed the newest version when in the second computer my programm didnt run with the Qt creator I thought that I installed too many Qt things there so I formatted and now installed things only from the linux repository (sudo apt-get installed)

Comment: Are the libraries on the same location? If I were you, I'd use LD_LIBRARY_PATH on launch. If you want to do it properly, make a installation package, see: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linux-deployment.html

Comment: yes they are And even no single error about the Qcustom plot only about the Qt itself

Answer (score -3):

Solve my problem:
The thing is that all Qt programs are hardware dependent and not software dependent like CODE::BLOCKS (thus will need dependencies externally)
What you have to do is install the Qt Creator and recompile your program, but wait it wont be that easy what you have to do is in the project tab disable the output folder ao that the program will be executed internally then enable the output folder and say yes so that you will rewrite your output folder

Comment: Compiled binaries are not hardware dependent (as long as the same OS is used). A program compiled with GCC on Ubuntu will run on any Ubuntu as long as the libraries are present in the /lib/ folder of your distribution. Same goes for a .exe on WIndows, as long as the required dlls are found around the .exe. That's why people distribute binaries most of the time, and not the source code to compile

Comment: You are right as long as we talk about GCC not Qt-GCC If you just update ubuntu your Qt programm wont run at all but if you use the same hardware and anly install the Qt-default the and only then it will run without the need of recompiling That is what we did in my company actually I took another day to investigate the subject and on the hardware you can read on the Qt site

Comment: As far as I know, Qt uses the regular GCC (or CLang) to compile its programs. There is no Qt-GCC. Only GCC compiling your source and linking Qt's libraries.

Comment: Then you are wrong install and you will see it I cannt upload a picture here otherwise I would show you

Comment: I have it installed, and it uses my global GCC installation. You can change that in the "Compiler" tab of the "Kit" menu, which allows you to choose a compiler, and its settings (for example, choosing CLang, GCC, or choose between x86 and x64)